# Alter Reset Password Link

Tags: 7, users

When a user resets his password he/she gets an email with a link which adds a message to the website and a hyperlink which it redirects him to the /user/[uid]/edit?token=... page.

How can i alter this link ?

Comment: Can you explain a little why you need to do this?  This may help get a solution to your root problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer mail a new link to user rather than altering the current link.

Use Tokens API to create user wise links.

```
function MYMODULE_token_info() {
  $info['tokens']['user']['passresetlink'] = array(
    'name' => t('Password Reset link 2'),
    'description' => t("Password Reset link 2"),
  );
  return $info;
}
```

and

```
function services_chat_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();
  if ($type == 'user' && !empty($data['user'])) {
    $user = $data['user'];
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'passresetlink':
          //$user = user_load($node->uid);
          //$newlink = make your link here.
          $replacements[$original] = $newlink;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```